# Resize image flutter

Tags: flutter, image, api, upload, resize

I need send picture from camera to API server. Image is too "heavy"..about 1,5 Mb. I need resize about to 120-150k
Which command can help me?

PS I'm using android studio

I tried command
maximum height or maximum width but server APi receive image with wrong rotation

Comment: Please add some code showing how you tried to use the maximum height/maximum width commands so we can better advise on a solution.